# Bootstrap 4 tabs

Tags: html, tabs, bootstrap-4, head

Ok guys I'm trying to make dynamic tabs with bootstrap 4, something like this: `https://codepen.io/jek/pen/BoWNRy` [I didn't wrote it]

In any case is I paste this code locally it don't work, I display the 3 tabs but I can see the text only in the first and I don't know why.
Here is my head [HTML]:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: add jquery to youe code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this `links` and `scripts` instead yours:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I took it from here:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/default.asp

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link  active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-selected="true">profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">buzz</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">references</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: First thanks for support, second how can I display at the load of the page the first tab[Profile tab ]?If you note I have to click another tab then re-click the first tab for view the content of the first tab, how can I see the content at the load of the page?

Comment: see my edit please `<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="profile">...</div>`

Answer (score 2):

An improvement to the accepted answer:

The first tab will not fade/animate. To fix that, replace:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="profile">...</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
```

with:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="profile">...</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
```